# AngularJs integration with Eclipse over Maven & Jersey

Tags: java, angularjs, eclipse, maven

I am creating an AngularJs project with RESTful API providing JSON data.

I need to develop complete project in Ecplise IDE as I am using Java classes to generate RESTful resources.

Problem is I don't know how to make Eclipse understand AngularJs.

I have included my javascripts and html pages in the project directory and while running it is this error:

```
http://localhost:7070/storyBoard/src/main/lib/angular-resource.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

It is unable to find my scripts I have provided path of in my project's directory structure.

Here is the directory structure:

[image: Directory Structure]

I am using Jersey framework for Maven. Is it even possible to integrate Angular this way? if not what other way can I accomplish this?

Here is the index.html template:

```html
<html ng-app="Writer">
<head>
    <script src="src/main/webapp/ajs/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="src/main/webapp/ajs/angular-route.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="src/main/webapp/ajs/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
 <script src="src/main/webapp/ajs/app.js"></script>
    <script src="src/main/webapp/ajs/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" ng-model="name" />
hello {{name}}
<h1>hello</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All static recources (such as css, js, html files) should be located in **webapp** directory instead of **lib** directory.

For web application the root directory is **webapp**. So the path should start with this directory, e.g.

http://localhost:7070/storyBoard/static/js/angular-resource.min.js

coresponds to

webapp/static/js/angular-resource.min.js

Comment: I changed the directory and moved my scripts to `webapp/ajs/angular-resource.js`. But still same error and it is looking for the script in this path: `http://localhost:7070/storyBoard/src/main/webapp/ajs/angular.min.js `.

Shouldn't it be `http://localhost:7070/storyBoard/ajs/angular.min.js` ?

Comment: You should also change the path in your HTML file. Please share your html where the path is specified.

Comment: Try <script src="ajs/angular.min.js"></script> in your html file

Comment: thnx..changing path to only `ajs/angular.min.js` worked!

Answer (score 0):

Move the angular JS files(/lib) into /webapp/ajs.
Try
http://localhost:7070/storyBoard/ajs/angular-resource.min.js

Comment: I moved my scripts to `webapp/ajs/angular-resource.js`. Still it can't locate any one script